# Why show invalid date. How to get input on Landon's current date time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

1. Why show an invalid date?
2. How to get input on Landon's current date time?
   N.B: In my project moment.tz() is not working.

```
<script>
let time = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }));
// let time = date.toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone: 'Europe/London'});
let prevRefreshTime="2023-01-15 05:20:09" //landon time
let startTime=moment(moment(prevRefreshTime).format('HH:mm:ss'), "HH:mm:ss");
let endTime=moment(moment(time).format('HH:mm:ss'), "HH:mm:ss");
let minutes =Math.abs(moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).as('minutes'));
</script>
```

**Example :**
previous time:2023-01-15 06:35:56 (London timezone)
current time : current London time
minutes=previous - current time

Answer (score 0):

After working with your code sample, there are several changes I had to make   to fix it.

Here is the reply link with the code fixes https://replit.com/join/opxdiovkin-drewg

Below is the code for your quick reference

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
let endTime = moment().tz('Europe/London');
let prevRefreshTime="2023-01-15 05:20:09" //london time
let startTime=moment(prevRefreshTime)
let minutes = Math.abs(endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes'));

console.log('minutes', minutes)
```

1. You were just using moment but the `.tz()` function can be used if you use `moment-timezone`, which has moment loaded underneath in its package. So you can just use `moment-timezone` to use the `.tz()` function and moment functions Here is the link to `moment-timezone` https://momentjs.com/timezone/.

Run `npm install moment-timezone` to use the package

If you are using jquery or vanilla js, try using a CDN import of the library or just downloading `moment.min.js` and importing it as a script into your project. Exclude the `require` statement at the beginning because it should already be imported.

Here is a Repl for a vanilla js version you can use https://replit.com/join/hraodvrlaf-drewg

2. You were also calling moment() functions within moment() functions which complicates the code. You don't need to format the dates until after calculation.
3. The `diff` function must have a second param with the unit you want to want to receive the difference result in. I added that in.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'moment-timezone' - Showen this error.

Comment: You need to run npm install moment-timezone to install the package

Comment: I am using jquery moment js .

Comment: Updated the post for you to try to use a script tag import

Comment: Also added an example repl you can click to and reference as a running example